# Mocha finding user from MongoDb in the beginning while it is created later

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I am trying to figure out how the user can be found from the database in the beginning of this code, while the user is created later in the code.

The Mocha documentation says

> Tests can appear before, after, or interspersed with your hooks. Hooks will run in the order they are defined, as appropriate; all before() hooks run (once), then any beforeEach() hooks, tests, any afterEach() hooks, and finally after() hooks (once).

```
var assert = require('assert');
var express = require('express');
var status = require('http-status');
var superagent = require('superagent');
var wagner = require('wagner-core');

var URL_ROOT = 'http://localhost:3000';
var PRODUCT_ID = '000000000000000000000001';

describe('User API', function() {
  var server;
  var Category;
  var Product;
  var User;

  before(function() {
    var app = express();

    models = require('./models')(wagner);

    Category = models.Category;
    Product = models.Product;
    User = models.User;

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      User.findOne({}, function(error, user) {
        assert.ifError(error);

        req.user = user;
        console.log(user);
        next();
      });
    });

    app.use(require('./api')(wagner));

    server = app.listen(3000);
  });

  after(function() {
    server.close;
  });

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    Category.remove({}, function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      Product.remove({}, function(error) {
        assert.ifError(error);
        User.remove({}, function(error) {
          assert.ifError(error);
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    var categories = [
      { _id: 'Electronics' },
      { _id: 'Phones', parent: 'Electronics' },
      { _id: 'Laptops', parent: 'Electronics' },
      { _id: 'Bacon' }
    ];

    var products = [
      {
        name: 'LG G4',
        category: { _id: 'Phones', ancestors: ['Electronics', 'Phones'] },
        price: {
          amount: 300,
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      },
      {
        _id: PRODUCT_ID,
        name: 'Asus Zenbook Prime',
        category: { _id: 'Laptops', ancestors: ['Electronics', 'Laptops'] },
        price: {
          amount: 2000,
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Flying Pigs Farm Pasture Raised Pork Bacon',
        category: { _id: 'Bacon', ancestors: ['Bacon'] },
        price: {
          amount: 20,
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      }
    ];

    var users = [{
      profile: {
        username: 'vkarpov15',
        picture: 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/550304223036854272/Wwmwuh2t.png'
      },
      data: {
        oauth: 'invalid',
        cart: []
      }
    }];
    Category.create(categories, function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      Product.create(products, function(error) {
        assert.ifError(error);
        User.create(users, function(error) {
          assert.ifError(error);
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });

  it('can save users cart', function(done) {
    var url = URL_ROOT + '/me/cart';

    superagent.
      put(url).
      send({
        data: {
          cart: [{ product: PRODUCT_ID, quantity: 1 }]
        }
      }).
      end(function(error,res) {

        assert.ifError(error);
        assert.equal(res.status, status.OK);
        User.findOne({}, function(error, user) {

          assert.ifError(error);
          assert.equal(user.data.cart.length, 1);
          assert.equal(user.data.cart[0].product, PRODUCT_ID);
          assert.equal(user.data.cart[0].quantity, 1);
          done();
        });
      });
  });

})
```

How can the user 'vkarpov15' be found here, whilst the user is created in the beforeEach function that comes later.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      User.findOne({}, function(error, user) {
        assert.ifError(error);

        req.user = user;
        console.log(user);
        next();
      });
    });
```

It is created here, later in the code:

```
Category.create(categories, function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      Product.create(products, function(error) {
        assert.ifError(error);
        User.create(users, function(error) {
          assert.ifError(error);
          done();
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The user is not queried there, that code just registers an express middleware that will query the user before each request to the server. As you can see, the request is issued  in an `it` test case, but a user is created before every test case, see the `beforeEach` block.

ps: You miss the parenthesis after `server.close()` in the after block.

Comment: I understand that the user is created in the beforeEach block. But in the document it says that the before block comes before the beforeEach block. So how can the before block have access to the user created in the beforeEach block?

Comment: As I said, the before block does not access the user. It only registers an express middleware (app.use) that gets the user, but it is not invoked there.

Comment: I see. So what is the function of the block and where does it get invoked?

Comment: @DowinskiField, was this answer helpful? If so, please check it as the correct one.